# How to avoid a rails 3 app from saving in development.log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to keep my rails 3 app from saving all the development logs in the development.log because its making my file bigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switching it entirely off is a very bad idea. You can make it put less transactions in it by specifying a log level like:

```
config.log_level = :info
```

in the config/environments/development.rb file. For the various options look here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Answer (score 7):

You can either do this in your:

```
application.rb
```

Or if you only want to disable for specific environments do this in the specific env config, in your case:

```
config/environments/development.rb
```

You're probably looking for some or all of the following settings:

```
config.logger
config.active_record.logger
config.action_controller.logger
config.action_view.logger
config.action_mailer.logger
config.active_resource.logger
```

If you set any of them to nil e.g.:

```
config.active_record.logger = nil
```

It should disable logging for that specific component. You can experiment with these to disable logging for specific components or set all of them to nil to get no logging.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, in a rails-app, there is a configuration-file, where you can set development-, production-, staging - specific configuration-data for logging, database-binding, bootstraps,...
Maybe you check these file, if there are no attributes defined for logging, check out, if you´re logging-level is set to the appropriate value.

Link: [Click](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoConfigureLogging)

greets